# SQL - Display Months as columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server table that has `Start` (1-1-2017) and `End` (1-1-2022) dates for contracts with invoices being generated each month for current and past months.

I would like to display months as columns even when no invoice has been generated, is that possible with just SQL / Pivot tables or a table with dates as calendar must be created?

I have worked with this code so far.

```
WITH CTE_MyTable AS
(
     SELECT
         FORMAT(MIN(StartDate), 'yyyy-MM') AS [MyDate] 
     FROM
         MyTable 

     UNION ALL

     SELECT 
         FORMAT(MIN(DATEADD(month, 1, StartDate)), 'yyyy-MM') AS [MyDate] 
     FROM
         MyTable
     WHERE 
         FORMAT(DATEADD(month, 1, StartDate),'yyyy-MM') <= (SELECT FORMAT(MAX(EndDate), 'yyyy-MM') AS [MyDate] FROM MyTable)
)
SELECT [MyDate] 
FROM CTE_ MyTable 
GROUP BY MyDate
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It definitely is possible, but we'd need to see sample data and expected results. The help documents that @Eric posted are really helpful, which I know is odd for most sites. In addition, I think [**this post**](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql) is really helpful to newer members. Sample data and expected results would really help though, cheers!

Comment: Were you attempting recursion?  There is none in that example code.

Comment: The SQL Server documentation for Pivot: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 0):

So let's say your table looked like this (using temp variable so you can just copy/paste/test):

```
DECLARE @sale TABLE(saledate DATE, saleamt MONEY);
INSERT @sale VALUES ('20170103',500),('20170128',266),('20170303',4002),('20170409',25);
```

Note that I'm only doing 6 months for simplicity. The following query get the count of sales per month (first query) and the sum of the sales for the second query:

```
DECLARE @sale TABLE(saledate DATE, saleamt MONEY);
INSERT @sale VALUES ('20170103',500),('20170128',266),('20170303',4002),('20170409',25);

SELECT
   [201701] = COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(t.saledate)=2017 AND MONTH(t.saledate) = 1 THEN 1 END),
   [201702] = COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(t.saledate)=2017 AND MONTH(t.saledate) = 2 THEN 1 END),
   [201703] = COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(t.saledate)=2017 AND MONTH(t.saledate) = 3 THEN 1 END),
   [201704] = COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(t.saledate)=2017 AND MONTH(t.saledate) = 4 THEN 1 END),
   [201705] = COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(t.saledate)=2017 AND MONTH(t.saledate) = 5 THEN 1 END),
   [201706] = COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(t.saledate)=2017 AND MONTH(t.saledate) = 6 THEN 1 END)
FROM @sale t;

SELECT
   [201701] = ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(t.saledate)=2017 AND MONTH(t.saledate) = 1 THEN t.saleamt END),0),
   [201702] = ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(t.saledate)=2017 AND MONTH(t.saledate) = 2 THEN t.saleamt END),0),
   [201703] = ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(t.saledate)=2017 AND MONTH(t.saledate) = 3 THEN t.saleamt END),0),
   [201704] = ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(t.saledate)=2017 AND MONTH(t.saledate) = 4 THEN t.saleamt END),0),
   [201705] = ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(t.saledate)=2017 AND MONTH(t.saledate) = 5 THEN t.saleamt END),0),
   [201706] = ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(t.saledate)=2017 AND MONTH(t.saledate) = 6 THEN t.saleamt END),0)
FROM @sale t;
```

These queries return:

```
201701      201702      201703      201704      201705      201706
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
2           0           1           1           0           0


201701                201702                201703                201704                201705                201706
--------------------- --------------------- --------------------- --------------------- --------------------- ---------------------
766.00                0.00                  4002.00               25.00                 0.00                  0.00
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to pivot columns in SQL- using the `Pivot()` function (Microsoft Documentation at:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017)

To display months as columns (1 to 12) the `Pivot()` function assigns values to (hard-coded) columns.  Implemented correctly, there are NULLS where the aggregation doesn't occur due to lack of records.  The implied way to replace NULLS with zeroes is by using the `COALESCE()` function.

The year values of the pivoted data should be grouped and while there is no specific `Group By` for a pivot, this is implied by how the **SourceTable** query is written.

In this example code I use the same exact format as the official documentation; with the exception that I additionally group by year and `COALESCE` NULLs with 0's.

What I am doing is counting the number of records for a given month and year:

```
SELECT yearval
      ,COALESCE([1], 0) [Jan]
      ,COALESCE([2], 0) [Feb]
      ,COALESCE([3], 0) [Mar]
      ,COALESCE([4], 0) [Apr]
      ,COALESCE([5], 0) [May]
      ,COALESCE([6], 0) [Jun]
      ,COALESCE([7], 0) [Jul]
      ,COALESCE([8], 0) [Aug]
      ,COALESCE([9], 0) [Sep]
      ,COALESCE([10], 0) [Oct]
      ,COALESCE([11], 0) [Nov]
      ,COALESCE([12], 0) [Dec]
FROM      
(SELECT YEAR([Your_Date_Column_Here]) AS [yearval]
       ,MONTH([Your_Date_Column_Here]) AS [monthval]           
   FROM [Your_Table_Name_Here]) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
  COUNT(monthval) FOR monthval IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12])  
) AS PivotTable
```

Would produce this output in my test database:

```
yearval Jan    Feb     Mar     Apr     May     Jun     Jul     Aug     Sep     Oct     Nov     Dec
2015    1952   1122    1678    2364    1125    1308    1414    2103    1031    1340    2506    1015    
2016    1123   1413    1568    1421    1278    1252    1048    1290    1251    1571    2647    1253
2017    0      0       0       3       0       1241    2377    2714    6724    1388    1521    1243
2018    2127   2118    2449    2330    2687    3833    3279    883     0       0       0       0
```